# Implement a scrollview with cocos2d-x 3.6

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

wondering if anyone knows how to implement a scroll view in cocos2d-x 3.6 (C++). All the tutorials I have found are for earlier cocos2d-x versions.

Thanks

I added my code below, I can get the grey scrollview box to show but it cant be scrolled and the buttons don't appear on it:

header files: "CocosGUI.h" and "cocos-ext.h"

```
//add scroll view
Size scollFrameSize = Size(visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height/4);
auto scrollView = cocos2d::ui::ScrollView::create();
scrollView->setContentSize(scollFrameSize);
scrollView->setBackGroundColorType(cocos2d::ui::Layout::BackGroundColorType::SOLID);
scrollView->setBackGroundColor(Color3B(200, 200, 200));
scrollView->setPosition(Point(0, visibleSize.height/1.5));
scrollView->setDirection(cocos2d::ui::ScrollView::Direction::HORIZONTAL);
scrollView->setBounceEnabled(true);
scrollView->setTouchEnabled(true);
auto containerSize = Size(scollFrameSize.width*2, scollFrameSize.height*2);
 scrollView->setInnerContainerSize(containerSize);

this->addChild(scrollView);


auto button1 = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
button1->setColor(Color3B(250, 200, 50));
button1->setTouchEnabled(true);
button1->setContentSize(Size(100, 100));
button1->setPosition(Point(containerSize.width / 4, containerSize.height / 2));
scrollView->addChild(button1);

auto button2 = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
button2->setColor(Color3B(250, 200, 50));
button1->setContentSize(Size(100, 100));
button2->setTouchEnabled(true);
button2->setPosition(Point(containerSize.width / 8, containerSize.height / 2));
scrollView->addChild(button2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, It was scrolling but I added my buttons wrong. For anyone who is interested add a button like this

```
auto button1 = ui::Button::create();
button1->setTouchEnabled(true);
button1->ignoreContentAdaptWithSize(false);
button1->setContentSize(Size(100, 100));
button1->loadTextures("pic1.png", "pic2.png");
button1->setPosition(Point(containerSize.width / 8, containerSize.height / 2));
scrollView->addChild(button1);
```

Comment: i think the button swallows the touch event, so the scrollview can't response to the touch move event. you can add an eventListener with larger priority but will not swallow touches,  pass the event to scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
Size scroll_size = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
Size container_size = Size(scroll_size.width * 2, scroll_size.height);
Layer* container = Layer::create();
container->setContentSize(container_size);
ScrollView* scroll = ScrollView::create(scroll_size, container);
mScroll->setDelegate(this);
mScroll->setDirection(ScrollView::Direction::HORIZONTAL);
```

1.size of container should be larger than size of scrollview

2.add child to container, not scrollview

3.implement ScrollViewDelegate

Comment: Didn't work. I am getting errors on line 5 (too many arguments) and on line 6 (no member named 'set delegate' in cocos2d::ui::ScrolView)

Comment: I added my code above, please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: @ctapp1 there are two Scrollviews in cocos2dx, you are using cocos/ui/widgets/UIScrollview and i meant cocos/extensions/GUI/CCScrollview